# XCODE Instruments app launch não aparece app life cycle

Tags: xcode

Estava vendo a [WWDC 2019](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/423/) e quando ele utiliza o `Instruments` para verificar o tempo em `ms` de abertura do app e mostrar informações do app life cycle na `track`, porém quando vou fazer isso em um app demo para estudo, não aparece essa informação. Alguém sabe se precisa fazer alguma configuração para que seja mostrado essa informação?

Imagem de como aparece a informação do app life cycle na WWDC:

[image: Imagem de como aparece a informação do app life cycle na WWDC]

Como aparece no projeto que fiz de exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver isso?